# What database privileges to grant to the user?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, database-security

I am making a network based Android application. I have created a server on my web hosting. I have used PHP and MySQL to handle database operations, now I want to assign a user to this database and grant him/her privileges so as to manipulate data.

However I am not sure which privileges I should grant to the user and which not, I have attached a screen shot to the page asking me to grant privileges, I want to know what will be secure and what can cause me potential harm.

[image]

Comment: Why would you ever give a user direct access to manipulate the database? The database layer should handle the request and act accordingly. I can't see this practice being beneficial in the least.

Comment: The whole purpose of granting a single user access to database, is for connection purpose and to run the queries. This database access is not for the users who use my application but it is kind of a bridge between the users and the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need  [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) (*Create, Read, Update, Delete*) privileges.

So **DELETE**, **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, **SELECT** and **EXECUTE**(if you have some stored procedures to call) should suffice!

Comment: Thanks mate, I was thinking of the same, but somewhere I was confused!